# looking for possible queries to display output similar to pivot table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a table as below

```
column_date | color | qty | supplier | location
1 June 2012 | red   | 2   | XY       | A wing
1 June 2012 | red   | 1   | AB       | A wing
1 June 2012 | blue  | 4   | CD       | A wing
1 June 2012 | blue  | 1   | XY       | B wing
2 June 2012 | yellow| 13  | CD       | B wing
2 June 2012 | green | 45  | CD       | A wing
2 June 2012 | blue  | 32  | AB       | A wing
2 June 2012 | red   | 37  | XY       | A wing
2 June 2012 | red   | 2   | XY       | B wing
2 June 2012 | red   | 1   | AB       | A wing
2 June 2012 | blue  | 4   | CD       | A wing
3 June 2012 | red   | 1   | AB       | B wing
3 June 2012 | blue  | 4   | CD       | A wing
3 June 2012 | blue  | 1   | XY       | B wing
3 June 2012 | yellow| 13  | CD       | B wing
3 June 2012 | green | 45  | CD       | A wing
3 June 2012 | blue  | 32  | AB       | A wing
```

And I would like to have a output like below. I'm not sure if it's possible in query and I have no idea how can I start if it's possible. I'm looking for your advise or possible queries to display output like this. Thank you.

```
                                    Supplier
Date           |        XY         |        CD          |       AB
               | A wing  | B wing  | A wing  | B wing   | A wing  | B wing
1 June 2012    |  2      |  1      |  4      | 0        | 1       | 0
2 June 2012    | 37      |  2      |  49     | 13       | 33      | 0
3 June 2012    | 0       |  1      |  49     | 13       | 32      | 1
Total          | 39      |  4      | 102     | 26       | 66      | 1
```

Comment: It's possible to get a result set like this in SQL, EXCEPT for getting the headings the way you show them. A returned result set has metadata for each separate column. I don't know of a way (in SQL) to get headings like that for a "group" of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT column_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN supplier = 'XY' AND location = 'A wing' THEN qty END) AS 'XY A wing',
    MAX(CASE WHEN supplier = 'XY' AND location = 'B wing' THEN qty END) AS 'XY B wing',
    MAX(CASE WHEN supplier = 'CD' AND location = 'A wing' THEN qty END) AS 'CD A wing',
    MAX(CASE WHEN supplier = 'CD' AND location = 'B wing' THEN qty END) AS 'CD B wing',
    MAX(CASE WHEN supplier = 'AB' AND location = 'A wing' THEN qty END) AS 'AB A wing',
    MAX(CASE WHEN supplier = 'AB' AND location = 'B wing' THEN qty END) AS 'AB B wing'
FROM @t
GROUP BY column_date
```

### [DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75130)

**Update:** What you are looking for here is how to [*pivot*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) your columns, but the problem with your query is there is no aggregate column you can aggregate the other columns with when you `GROUP BY column_date`. Since you need to `GROUP BY column_date`, then the other columns need to either be in the `GROUP BY clause` or contained in a an aggregate function. Therefore I used an aggregate function `MAX` as a work around. This is fine if you know the values you want to pivot forehand. But if you want to pivot unknown or changing number of values, then you need to do this dynamically. Try to search for *Dynamic Pivoting in SQL Server* and you will find a lot of workarounds using dynamic SQL. For example see these two articles:

- [Dynamic Pivoting in SQL Server.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27776/Dynamic-Pivoting-in-SQL-Server)
- [Dynamic Cross-Tabs/Pivot Tables.](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables)

Comment: Many thanks. It works fine. But I have a question on this.
May I know what max function in your code exactly does to produce the desired output?`
`And is it possible to be done dynamically without specifying each field names ?`